# How to show csv file data in html page?

Tags: html, csv, import-from-csv

i have a csv file like this:

```
number:Int,english,french,german
1,one,un,eins
2,two,deux,zwei
3,three,trois,drei
4,four,quattre,four
5,five,cinque,fuenf
6,six,six,sechs
7,seven,sept,sieben
8,eight,huit,acht
9,nine,neuf,neun
10,ten,dix,zehn
```

and a html file like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>Reading values into a table</title></head>
<body>

<table datasrc='#data'>

  <thead>
 <tr><th>Number</th><th>English</th><th>French</th><th>German</th></tr>
 </thead>

  <tbody> <tr>
 <td><span datafld='number'> </span></td>
 <td><span datafld='english'></span></td>
 <td><span datafld='french'> </span></td>
 <td><span datafld='german'> </span></td>
  </tbody>

</table>


<object ID=data classid="clsid:333C7BC4-460F-11D0-BC04-0080C7055A83">
  <param nAme="http://insforia.com/try/Data.CSV" value="Data.csv">
  <param nAme="UseHeader" value="true">
 </object>

</body>
</html>
```

the problem is i am not getting the csv file's data in my html page .. i have this requirement that i have to show the data in html so any help?

Comment: Why are you not using a server side technology to parse the CSV and display it? Consider that the tabular data control you are using will not be available on many platforms and probably only work on Internet Explorer.

Comment: i have a requirement that i can use something like asp.net

Comment: i am using simple html table for this

Comment: Great. Doesn't explain why you are using only client side technologies - you are not using asp.net at all here.

Comment: Please explain what server side technology you intend to use and what you have tried? Where exactly are you stuck? At the moment, this is not a question that can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

you should know that Tabular Data Control (TDC) works only with Internet Explorer so do not bother yourself trying with another browser. 
Your problem is first parameter given to object with Data id, you must change its name attribute to DataURL, like this :

```
<object ID=data classid="clsid:333C7BC4-460F-11D0-BC04-0080C7055A83">
  <param nAme="DataURL" value="data.csv">
  <param nAme="UseHeader" value="true">
 </object>
```

More information about Tabular Data Control :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531356(v=vs.85).aspx